# Por que "vector" é considerado uma "list" em alguns casos?

Tags: r

Considere os objetos:

```
 for(i in 1:6){
  names<-paste0("var",i)
  assign(names,runif(30,20,100))
 }

dataset<-do.call(
  cbind.data.frame,
  mget(ls(pattern='*v'))
)

cluster<-kmeans(dataset,centers=3)
dataset$kmeans<-as.factor(cluster[['cluster']])

mylist<-split(dataset,dataset$kmeans)
 names(mylist)<-paste('dataset',seq_along(mylist),sep='')
```

Tentei eliminar APENAS os `vector`s do `globalenv()`:

```
rm(list=ls(Filter(is.vector,mget(ls()))))
```

Mas, os objetos `dataset` (um `data.frame`) e `cluster` (uma `list`) permanecerem no `globalenv()`.
Porém, `mylist` e os `vector`s foram eliminados.

Pergunto:

- por que `mylist` foi eliminado e `cluster` permaneceu (ambos tem `typeof` `list`)?
- por que um objeto de classe `list` foi eliminado, como ocorreu com `mylist` (especifiquei `vector` como argumento)?

Comment: Não vai dar para escrever uma resposta agora. Mas a dica está [aqui](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#List-objects). Listas são uma vetor genérico. Os outros vetores são vetores atômicos.

Comment: A função `is.vector()` tem um argumento `mode` que pode receber os `typeof(x)` básicos ou "list" ou "expression" ou "any". Ver  `?is.vector`.

Comment: Mas, por que o objeto `cluster` (uma `list`) ainda permanece. Ele possui o mesmo `typeof` de `mylist` (i.e., `list`) e esta é eliminada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O atributo que `cluster` herda não é `list` mas sim `kmeans`. `is.vector` deve procurar o atributo classe de um objeto (caso a tenha), veja essa exemplo:

```
baz <- c(1:10)
is.vector(baz) # TRUE
class(baz) <- "brasil"
is.vector(baz) # FALSE
class(baz) <- "integer"
is.vector(baz) # TRUE
class(baz) <- "list"
is.vector(baz) # TRUE
```

No console `?typeof`:

> Description
>
> `typeof` determines the (R internal) type or storage mode of any object

Portanto, `typeof` não olha o atributo e, sim, o "tipo ou modo de armazenamento". E o `is.vector` olha para o atributo (`?is.vector`):

> ...
>
> `is.vector` returns `TRUE` if `x` is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes other than names. It returns `FALSE` otherwise.
>
> ...
>
> If `mode` = "any", `is.vector` may return `TRUE` for the atomic modes, list and expression. For any mode, it will return `FALSE` if x has any attributes except names.